# Do you have any directive for checkbox?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I want to get some attr's value in a checkbox  when it is checked,is there any directive for it?

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996145/checkbox-directive-in-angular/36996405#36996405

Comment: why use a directive just for it? haha there is no need

Comment: you can achieve that by injecting `$attrs` into the controller, refer this answer for more clarity, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29485941/1677272

Comment: sorry everyone....   I forget say that   they are multi checkbox produced by ng-repeat .   is there any great way or useful directive?

Answer (score 1):

use the native `ng-model`:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="valid"/>
```

and in your controller:

```
 $scope.valid //true or false
```

Comment: but  if they are  produced by ng-repeat, how can i get them?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="box" ng-true-value="'yes'" ng-false-value="'no'">
```

In the above example the variable `$scope.box` will be set to `'yes'` when the box is checked; `'no'` when unchecked.

For more information, see [AngularJS input[checkbox] Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D).